# boostrap align input field

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, input

My apology for the poorly stated question. I am new to `css` and `boostrap`. I am writing `form` that uses `table` format in `html` sense in `react`.

I was able to resize `input` width via `col-sm-3` however that pushed the input field to far right. `xxxxxx` represents the width. Is there a way that I can push it next to the `label`?

```
<form name='foo'>
    <div className='row'>
       .... // for Enter Your Address
    </div>
    <div className='row'>
      <div className='col'>
        <label>Enter Your Age</label>
      </div>
      <div className='col col-sm-3'>
        <Field component={InputField} name='age' placeholder='xxxxx' type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

From

```
Enter your address: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Enter Your Age:                 xxxxxx
```

To

```
Enter your address: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Enter Your Age:     xxxxxx
```

Comment: Apply the size class to the other column instead so the label is the smaller column The one that doesn’t have an explicit size is probably just filling in the remaining space.

Comment: What Version Of bootstrap?
do you have any other css files that are overriding those classes?

Comment: Just add `form-inline` class to `form` and remove all the `row` and `col`, just put `label` and `Field` in wrapper div with class `form-group`.

Comment: I greatly appreciate all of your time to reply back to this thread. I use `boostrap 4.3.1`. I updated my question by adding another row `Enter your address` which was important piece to mention but I inadvertently forgot about. I am pursuing `inputField` elements to be left aligned.

Comment: Answer is found from fellow engineer whom I work with. I was told to remove `table` format then simply apply fixed width on label `{ minWidth: '200px' }` as an example, That way I  believe all the labels have consistent width which somehow fixed `inputFields` to be all aligned in left side.

Answer (score 0):

I never use Bootstrap with react (just with simple html files). But by using Bootstrap logic i did this with the last version of bootstrap : (The first form represents what you did, the third form is just a code from [Boostrap inline form sample](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#inline-forms) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#inline-forms). In my opinion the third method is the best :

```
<form name='foo'>
  <div>FORM 1</div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <label>Enter Your Age</label>
    </div>
    <div class='col col-sm-3'>
      <input class="form-control" name='age' placeholder='xxxxx' type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form name='foo'>
  <div>FORM 2</div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <label for="age2">Enter Your Age</label>
    </div>
    <div class='col col-sm-3'>
      <input id="age2" class="form-control" name='age' placeholder='xxxxx' type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
    </form>

<div>FORM 3</div>
<form name='foo' class="form-inline">
  <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="age3">Enter your age</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="age3" placeholder="xxxxxx">
</form>
```

You will have to do the match for React attributes. 
[Here is a picture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFa8I.png)

In your code, By using the class **col** for the label's div, you're saying that the div will occupy all the available space and leave only what is needed for the div with the class **col-sm-3**. That is the reason why you have this big space.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need col classes at all. The below code is enough.

```
<form name='foo'>
<div className='row'>
  <div>
    <label>Enter Your Age</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Field component={InputField} name='age' placeholder='xxxxx' type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use a custom class like below

```
<form name='foo'>
<div className='bar'>
  <div>
    <label>Enter Your Age</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Field component={InputField} name='age' placeholder='xxxxx' type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.bar { 
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <label>Enter Your Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
        <Field component={InputField} name='age' placeholder='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <label>Enter Your Age</label>
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
        <Field component={InputField} name='age' placeholder='xxxxx' type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```